# Cannot connect to localhost in SQL Server through windows authentication after changing the password of PC

Tags: sql-server, localhost, windows-authentication

Originally, I can connect to localhost in SQL Server through Windows authentication. But after I changed the login password of PC, I can't. Could you please help me figure out why?

Comment: what is the message? are your SQL Server service running?

Comment: The SQL Server service must be running because I can connect to other remote database. The message is as follow:

Comment: Cannot connect to localhost.

A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 2)

Comment: connect to other remote database does not mean your service is running.
You should change password at the sql server service first (if your sql server service running under your login pc)

Answer (score 0):

Not too much information provided... but that is common issue for many users.

Check the server account name in the SQL Server Configuration Manager.  If you run it under your account, you have to change the password for that service and restart it, or change it to use LocalSystem account.

Comment: "under your account" , "LocalSystem account", etc. Answer with no guidance and minimum picture make your answer confusing. Ask Zhiqiang, is he know what does your mean?

Answer (score 0):

- Open CMD (Ctrl+r) input "services.msc"
- Right Click SQL Server (Your Instance) - Properties

[image: services]

- Click Tab Log On

[image: Click Tab Log On]

- Fill this account : your user login
- Fill password : your user password, then confirm password then Ok.
- Back to services Right click your SQL Server [Instance Name] - Start (picture 1)
- Try re-login using windows account at SSMS

Comment: Changing account settings via services.msc is not recommended. It has to be done via SQL Configuration Manager, otherwise you may have incorrect windows registry settings. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/ms174212.aspx

Comment: as far as I know. It is ok.

Comment: your "has to" (has to be done via SQL) why it being a must?

Comment: I provided the link but you instead of reading it and learning something new, downvoted my answers LOL

Comment: MS is clearly saying:  Important: Always use SQL Server tools such as SQL Server Configuration Manager to change the account used by the SQL Server or SQL Server Agent services, or to change the password for the account.

Comment: continue:...  In addition to changing the account name, SQL Server Configuration Manager performs additional configuration such as setting permissions in the Windows Registry so that the new account can read the SQL Server settings. Other tools such as the Windows Services Control Manager can change the account name but do not change associated settings. If the service cannot access the SQL Server portion of the registry the service may not start properly.

Comment: If you don't believe MS documentation, run regmon and see what's happening in the registry and then same when you start the sql service.

Comment: Because it is rule how to correctly change the passwords for SQL2008+ servers. For clustered environments, there is another rule to change it, but it's not applicable here.

Comment: what's happening in the registry? You want to tell me something or what? Please give reason, why it is being a must? There is many helpdesk who activate server from services.msc, and change configs using services.msc

Comment: "clustered environments" ok thank you for your info.